# What is the relationship between Celtic harmonics and Celtic symbols?

Tags: symbolism, celtic

I've noticed that Celtic-sounding words are very sing-song. Is there a connection between this rhythm and their symbols, like the Celtic knot?

Comment: What are some examples of "Celtic-sounding words [that] are very sing-song"? This is not a typical observation.